# Finite threshold value for two-body binding

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, superconductivity

In his book *Introduction to Superconductivity*, Second Ed., Chapter 3.1, when discussing Cooper's [1956 paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.104.1189) and the formation of Cooper pairs, Tinkham states

> [...] it is well known that binding does not ordinarily occur in the two-body problem in three dimensions until the strength of the potential exceeds a finite threshold value.

I'm having trouble trying to understand what the author meant.

Take the hydrogen atom for example. If we rescale the potential strength by a positive quantity $\lambda$: $U(r)\rightarrow\lambda U(r)$, then the energy levels will just be rescaled according to $E_n \rightarrow \lambda E_n$. This means there will still be bound levels for any positive $\lambda$, no matter how small.

- **What did the author mean, then? Was he referring strictly to pairs of identical particles? Does it have something to do with Cooper's approximation of the attractive potential as a constant?**

---

@KevinKostlan 's answer below is very enlightening. However, as stated in the bounty, I'm still looking for a concrete source on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

**He is referring to short-ranged interactions that drop off much more steeply than inverse-square law**.

The standard particle-in-a-box has length L and infinite depth. But for 3D boxes with finite "depth" $E_{box}$ we don't always have bound states. Why is this?

The strictly mathematical answer is "there is no eigensolutions with energy < $E_{box}$". But this can also be seen from a scaling argument:

It takes energy to confine a particle to mostly fit into a region. The order of magnitude energy cost is $E_{confine}$~$\frac {h^2} {2m\lambda^2}$ *in any dimension*, where $\lambda$ is the size in which *most* of the particle is found. This is balanced against how much of the particle is actually in the box and the depth of the box: $E_{bind}$~$E_{box}min(1,L/\lambda^{D})$, where D is the dimension. In three dimensions, doubling $\lambda$ amounts to spreading the wavefunction and corresponding probability distribution out in all three axes.
In 1D, there will always be bound states. In 2D it is unclear under this crude scaling law if there are always bound states. However, in 3D if the box is too small or too shallow, no bound states can be found because $E_{bind}$ drops off too quickly as $\lambda$ increases.

For atoms, the potential well is inverse-linear (inverse square *force*) rather than a fixed box. This makes the scaling law $E_{bind}$~$Z/\lambda$ and guarantees bound states no matter how weak the binding forces are. However, for other systems we may have sharper drop-offs. For [two helium atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_dimer) they are attracted by an extremely weak van der Waals interaction which also drops off *very quickly*. In this case bound states only exist if the two atoms are *both* Helium-4 atoms. The case of interactions between electrons in a lattice is similarly short-ranged.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why the 3D case has sometimes no bound states, if the 1D one always does. Can't the eigestates of the 3D case be built by making a tensor product of 3 1D bound states? Also, could you provide a source for the derivation of the expressions you presented?

Comment: @Lucas: A tensor product solution would actually correspond to a three orthogonal, infinite slab-shaped potential wells summed together. This plot is an example of the well that corresponds to a tensor-product of solutions to two finite 1D wells (for 2D): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73571/how-to-solve-bound-states-of-2d-finite-rectangular-square-well

Comment: @Lucas: "infinite" means infinite along two axes, the depth is still finite.

Comment: I see. But doesn't that show that there are some steep, short-ranged interactions for which the bound states exist regardless of the potential strength? And despite that, could you still provide sources for the expressions $E_{confine}$ and $E_{bind}$ you used in your answer?

Comment: @LucasBaldo "Short ranged" means it has to be short-ranged in *all* axes, dropping off to zero in all directions faster than inverse-square force. $E_{confine}$ is the energy of a free-particle solution with a given De Broglie wavelength. This wavelength is to an order-of-magnitude the size of a ground-state bound particle's wavefunction.  $E_{bind}$ is scaled by the probability of a particle being inside the well if it were observed.

Comment: What is "dropping off to zero" in all directions, exactly? Do you mean the potential must go to a direction-independent (finite) constant at infinity? Also, I can see $E_{confine}$ being the energy of a free-particle, but it is not obvious to me how the probability of a particle being inside the well is proportional to $min(1, L/\lambda^D)$. How can I derive that or where can I find a derivation of it?

Comment: @Lucasbaldo yes that is what I mean by drop off to zero. The min formula is an order of magnitude much like big O notation. In 3D of we scale up a probability distribution 2 fold in all three dimensions it gets 8 times less dense. Thus the fraction in a small region drops off 8 fold. The box is a "small" region when $\lambda$ << $L$.

Comment: @Lucasbaldo. Correction: the box is small when $L << \lambda$.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand, but it's still a little bit confusing. Could you please point me to a book, paper or wikipedia article where I can read more about this? (So we can avoid extending this discussion even more)

Comment: @LucasBaldo I can't find any paper that makes my scaling law argument explicitly. However, I found a nice discussion about the helium dimer's wavefunction: http://interweave-consulting.blogspot.com/2016/12/the-enormous-helium-dimer.html.

The helium dimer is *barely* bound and only if both atoms are helium-4, so it shows what happens when the well is *almost* too shallow to allow a bound state.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is an interesting discussion and the Helium dimer is a nice example where a threshold interaction strength is required for the formation of bound states. I'm going to leave the question open for a few more days, however, in the hopes of finding a source with a more general discussion on the subject. Let me know if you find anything new!